# .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5 for networking applications

Tags: c#, networking

I'll be developing a C# networking application which will make use of UDP and will require lowest lag time and general good performance.
Is .NET 3.5 better suited for such applications? Is there any performance benifits/improvements in .NET 3.5?
Specificly I'll be using SocketAsyncEventArgs class. And I think it is available from only .NET 2.0SP1+?

Answer (score 2):

> Is .NET 3.5 better suited for such applications?

They are the same. Except that 3.5 is just a better language.

> Is there any performance benifits/improvements in .NET 3.5? Specificly I'll be using SocketAsyncEventArgs class. And I think it is available from only .NET 2.0SP1+?

The .NET 3.5 technically is just add-on on top of .NET 2.0.

So in 3.5 you will have all the same Pros/Cons of .NET 2.0 plus all the additional language improvements.

For me there is no doubt - .NET 3.5 would be my choice because of all the language sugar that heavily increases productivity.

Comment: Perticularly if one is starting from the ground up.

Comment: What about deployment? I like linq etc but will users like installing 3.5 with it's big size?

Comment: .Net 3.5 is only big if they need to install the full redistributable package

Comment: @Niran, comparing to the size of .NET 2.0, additional .NET 3.5 is not that significant and an end-user doesn't really care.

Comment: I'd love to see some figures for that claim.